# Update a table from another table in mysql and php where there are no NULLs in each column

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following tables

TableA.number_id

TableB.number_id

TableA.serial_id

TableB.serial_id

I want to update TableA.number_id with TableB number_id WHEN TableA serial_id == TableB serial_id except when TableA serial_id or TableB serial_id has no value i.e. is null or empty

This almost works except that I'm getting the first number_id inserted when TableA serial_id AND TableB serial_id has a NULL value, the "is not NULL" is being ignored.

```
$sql = "UPDATE TableA, TableB SET TableA.number_id = TableB.number_id WHERE TableA.serial_id = TableB serial_id AND TableA.serial_id IS NOT NULL";
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should do it:

```
UPDATE TableA a JOIN TableB b
  ON a.serial_id = b.serial_id
SET
  a.number_id = b.number_id
WHERE a.serial_id IS NOT NULL AND b.serial_Id IS NOT NULL
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you angelcool.net. I had some issues whether serial_id was in fact a Null value or just blank, in phpmyadmin the structure for this column is Default = Null and Null checked, but in browse view it s just showing as blank so I changed "IS NOT NULL" to !=' ' and that worked fine